# Both Have Denied Value how to get Count Both field for same Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 Fields 
Both Have Denied Value how to get Count Both field for same Column
[image]

Comment: HUH??? What do you mean by get count for same column? Are you trying to get the total number of "Denied" values across those two columns?

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be interpreted a couple of different ways.

This query will give you the number of rows where both `_CX_CD_REQ_LC_001` and `_CX_CD_REQ_LC_002` are equal to "Denied".

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count' 
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE _CX_CD_REQ_LC_001 = 'Denied'
  AND _CX_CD_REQ_LC_002 = 'Denied'
```

This one will give you the number of occurrences of the value of "Denied" regardless of which field it is in.

```
SELECT x.Count1 + y.Count2
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count1' 
    FROM [YourTable]
    WHERE _CX_CD_REQ_LC_001 = 'Denied'
) x
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count2' 
    FROM [YourTable]
    WHERE _CX_CD_REQ_LC_002 = 'Denied'
) y
```

Either of those what you want?

Noel